# Which 4-pin connector is this (similar to Molex Minifit)?

Tags: identification, connector

I'm trying to connect to the RS485 of my stove/furnace and it has a strange connector for this. I want to intercept the existing physical connection, so I need both plug and receptable.

Plug (each pin ~4x4 mm, total ~8x8 mm):

[image: Plug of the Connection]

Receptacle (Outside dimensions: 9.5x9.5 mm):

[image: Receptacle of the Connection]

It actually looks like a Molex Minifit connector, but it is not really. The size fits exactly, but the 2x2 Molex Minifit Connection has two rectangular holes and two trapezoid holes. This connection I have here only has one trapezoid hole.

I actually bought 2x2 Molex Minifit connectors and they don't fit. I also checked the Molex Microfit and they also don't seem to be the right thing.

How is this connector called and where can I buy a plug and a receptacle? Or, even better, where can I buy an extension cord (1:1 mapped) so I don't have to crimp my own cable?

Comment: There are many equivalents; you may find something of use from major manufacturers (TE, Samtec, etc.); it may also be a custom-keyed Mini-Fit (or equivalent), which will be much harder to find.

Comment: Molex Mega-fit?

Comment: Look at the plug REALLY REALLY REALLY close .. If you're lucky, and you get the right light angle, you may see a part number or a manufacturers name at least.

Comment: also mini-fit has square pins and this has round pins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a [TE Mini-Universal MATE-N-LOK](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=172159&DocType=Customer%20Drawing&DocLang=English).  The good news is that inline receptacles exist, so you can make an extension cable the "right" way.  The bad news is that it doesn't look like pin-to-socket jumpers exist and the crimper is $850.

Edit: there are also tap splices that will give you a clean pickoff if you can access the individual wires going into the plug.

Comment: I just wanted to say that I checked and this answer is indeed correct.